# Run javascript on other site using php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Right now I'm handling a web scraper and I have a small problem. Can I run some javascript code on that page via my scraper? Because some results appear just after the visitor selects a something, I can't get them from there. Here is the example: http://www.finnmatkat.fi/akkilahdot/Post.aspx

This the list for Helsinki, and if I want to select Vasaa I must select it from the drop down menu. So a new list will appear. I don't know how I could get here with my php scraper. I've heard something about the curl library that helps sending variables via GET or POST method. But I don't think if it is the case here. It is also possible to use ajax, but I can't get there. 
Could anybody give me a clue here?

Comment: [Do your web scraping with zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is really tricky!

Maybe in combination with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) some how? However that is not pure PHP anymore.

Another approach would be to build your own *PHP Browser*. Take [V8js](http://php.net/manual/en/class.v8js.php) a interpret all the stuff by your self. That would be a really cool solution! Okay, maybe a bit too much overhead … ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a request using curl and send the POST parameters. You can monitor the actual request and the headers that are sent and replicate them.